# UpdatePanel not working

Tags: asp.net

I have the following update panel but it doesn't seem to want to update. The AsyncPostBackTrigger GroupApply2 does not update and i'm really confused as to why. I've tried moving things around but no luck. Any thoughts? Script Manager is obviously specifid and I have the update running on other pages just fine.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPan01" runat="Server" UpdateMode="always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <p>
            How is this group applied?:
            <asp:DropDownList ID="GroupApply2" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GroupApply2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="To the Country " />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Just Your Site" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Commodity" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </p>
        <asp:Label ID="Build2" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="true"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GroupApply2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? The trigger for your Panel is inside your panel. So what is supposed to happen?
Also: why is there tons of unrelated elements outside your panel?

Comment: User clicks on the dropdown, the dropdown onselection change, then calls some c# code which as a test updates the .Text of label ID Build2

Comment: Please add the dropdown list code. Note that your ListItems have no values, only text.

Comment: protected void GroupApply2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Build2.Text = "sdsad";}

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out, sorry just needed some hand-holding i guess! My build works fine of c# code, i hashed out most of it and it worked so somewhere something was stopping it from working.

Thank you